# Computing points for farkle game in C

Tags: c

this a part of program(I didnt add all codes of functions written).
"roll_a_dice()" creats a number for each dice. and 
according to rule1, user will gain 50 points for each dice 5.
according to rule2, user will gain 100 points for combination of dice (1,1,1)
I wrote somehow but it looks inefficient. How can I write it with more efficient way?

note: I m not allowed to use array, pointers etc.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int compute_points(int ruleno)
{
    int k=0,i;
    switch(ruleno)
    {
        case 1:
            if(d1==5) k+=50;
            if(d2==5) k+=50;
            if(d3==5) k+=50;
            if(d4==5) k+=50;
            if(d5==5) k+=50;
            if(d6==5) k+=50; break;

        case 2:
            if(d1==1) i+=1;
            if(d2==1) i+=1;
            if(d3==1) i+=1;
            if(d4==1) i+=1;
            if(d5==1) i+=1;
            if(d6==1) i+=1;
            if(i=>3)  k=100 break;
    }

    return k;   
}

int main()
{
    int m,p1,p2,turn, t1,t2,ruleno,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,point;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("FARKLE GAME!");
    m=menu(m);

        ruleno=select_rule_number(ruleno);

        d1=roll_a_dice();
        d2=roll_a_dice();
        d3=roll_a_dice();
        d4=roll_a_dice();
        d5=roll_a_dice();
        d6=roll_a_dice();
        numberofdice(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6);

        point=compute_points(ruleno,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6);

    printf("Goodby!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: Actually, what does your compiler tell you about the syntax errors in the code?

Comment: No error, I just want to write the function shorter

Comment: Make an array of dice `int d[6]` and use `for` loops `for (i=0;i<6;i++) d[i]=roll_a_dice();`

Comment: using array is not allowed by teacher #user3386109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some C tricks to get a more elegant solution.

Try this:

```
result += 50 * ((d1 == 5) + (d2 == 5) + (d3 == 5) + (d4 == 5) + (d5 == 5) + (d6 == 5));
```

Do you see what this does?

First, the d1 == 5 is a boolean expression resulting in a true or false, so if it's 5 it will yield a 1. If not, a 0. So what you do is you collect the count of fives and multiply by 50. This would cut a huge chunk of your code to just one line.

Comment: What about for second rule?

Comment: Think about what it is that you want to achieve. You want three 1's. But this might very well be all 1's. (six 1's). So you want a bit of a generalized formula.

Such as this: 
result = 100 * ((d1 == 1) + (d2 == 1) + (d3 == 1) + (d4 == 1) + (d5 == 1) + (d6 == 1)) / 3

This will get you the count of 1's and divide it by 3, then award you 100 for each triplet.